# aws s3 static website hide content before login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application

i think about developing a static website hosted on amazon s3. my file structure would be something like

```
/login.html
/login.js
/hiddenContent/fileA.html
/hiddenContent/fileA.js
```

The website itself is written in Angular 1.x, so its a single page application.
My problem now is: login should be public, everyone can access this page. But everything in /hiddenContent folder should only be visible to authenticated users. since its angular, all content and controllers must be known at bootstrap ( loading ) time. but then, a user familiar with web techniques, can see the html and js which is already loaded ( but not filled with data ). but this must be avoided. How can i deal with that problem? html and controller javascript should be loaded AFTER login. with a server its not a problem, but s3 doesnt have any server.

tl;dr: how can i load html/javascript in a SPA after login?

Comment: You could have a separate html with its own authentication process which redirects you to the app with the necessary parameters when successfully authenticated. I believe trying to achieve this in one and the same SPA it'd become quite the hassle.

Comment: yeah, but how to redirect with parameters to a static website? there is no server which could read those parameters. please explain in more detail.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind would be Auth0. Load the login widget on your static website, when they log in successfully you'll get a JWT with their info. Send that JWT to the landing page of your SPA which loads it, verifies it using an Auth0 client and let them in? This is off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce security on an Amazon S3 static website via:

- **Pre-signed URLs** (but this needs an application to authenticate users and generated the pre-signed URLs), or
- By using **temporary AWS credentials** (which can be generated via the AWS Secure Token Service, but again you'd need an application to create the credentials), or
- By using **permanent AWS credentials** (but you should not use IAM to grant access to application users)

**Bottom line:** If you have no logic layer to check security and generate access credentials, then you cannot selectively protect an Amazon S3 static website.